# Send simple Ajax request to Python via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am new to python and I am trying to send a request to a python script with a machine learning model. I would like to get back the result of the model as a response in Ajax. My GUI is in basic HTML, CSS (no framework). How can I send the JSON data to python and get back the result in JavaScript? Below is my code...

My code

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var form_data = new FormData(this);
  form_data.append('subcounty', $('#subcounty_search').val());
  form_data.append('area', $('#area').val());
  $.ajax({
    url: 'add.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xml.open("POST", "tier match/run.py", true);
      xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xml.onload = function() {
        var dataReply = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
        alert(dataReply)
      }
      var dataSend = JSON.stringify({
        'home_type': $('input[name="home_type"]:checked').val(),
        'residence_type': $('input[name="residence_type"]:checked').val(),
        'bedrooms': $('#bedrooms').text(),
        'bathrooms': $('#bathrooms').text(),
        'occupancy': $('#occupancy').text(),
        'swimming': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="swimming"]:checked').val()),
        'wifi': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="wifi"]:checked').val()),
        'tv': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="tv"]:checked').val()),
        'workers': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="workers"]:checked').val()),
        'wheelchair': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="wheelchair"]:checked').val()),
        'parking': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="parking"]:checked').val()),
        'gym': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="gym"]:checked').val()),
        'kids': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="kids"]:checked').val()),
        'security': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="security"]:checked').val()),
        'garden': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="garden"]:checked').val()),
        'ac': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="ac"]:checked').val()),
        'pets': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="pets"]:checked').val()),
        'smokers': encodeHomeFeatures($('input[name="smokers"]:checked').val())
      });
      xml.send(dataSend)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer top">
  <form method="POST" id="form">
    <div class="content-wrap">
      <div class="container p-lg-0">

        <!-- start of description page-->
        <div class="description-page">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="section-heading ml-5">
                <h4 class="heading-title"><span class="heading-circle green"></span> Give a good description of your home</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="section-wrapper ml-5">
            <h6>Title</h6>
            <div class="col-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Christine's Spectacular Beach House" required>
            </div>
            <br>
            <h6>Description</h6>
            <div class="col-8">
              <textarea id="description" class="form-control" name="description" rows="8" cols="30" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <br>
            <h6>Insert an image of your house</h6>
            <div class="col-6">
              <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" onchange="displayname(this,$(this))" />
              <label for="upload" class="add-home-image">
                            <i class="fas fa-file-image"></i>&emsp;Upload an image
                        </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br><br>
          <input type="hidden" name="where" id="where" value="home">
          <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $customer_id; ?>">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="prev ml-5">
                <a href="#">Previous</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="submit">
                <button type="submit" id="completeAddHome" style="background-color: #FD5555;" class="btn btn-danger rounded-pill ml-3">Complete</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end of description page-->
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

I was trying a Http request but it wasn't working for me. I don't know if that's an option. Don't worry about the data in the JSON, I passed it through another function. How can I send that JSON to the Python script below and get a response.

Python Script (run.py)

```
import ml


house_features = [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

tier_prediction = ml.knn_prediction(house_features)

print(tier_prediction)
```

This script calls the ML model below which is a script called 'ml.py'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix



def knn_prediction(features):
    #house_features = [0,0,0,0,1,1,2,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
    data = pd.read_csv('/Users/Mariwa/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/HomeExchange/tier match/home_tier_dataset.csv')
    X = data.iloc[:,:-1].values
    Y = data.iloc[:, 18].values

    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.9)

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(X_train)
    X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
    X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
    classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)

    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

    check_value = np.array(features)

    tier_prediction = classifier.predict([check_value])
    tier = tier_prediction[0]

    return tier
```

Comment: You cannot run a python script like that. `$.ajax()` and `XMLHttpRequest` (which do the same thing) can only communicate with a web server (which seems to be PHP in your case). So to run a python script, you need to put it on the server, make a request to a suitable PHP script, have the PHP script run the python script while forwarding the POST data, then return the python output. You can in theory run a python web server (on the same machine but with a different port) so you don't have to go through PHP.

Comment: Also PLEASE use EITHER  - don't use $.ajax AND XMLHTTPRequest in the same code. Aso jQuery is considered a framework

Comment: Ooow! You can run a python script from PHP. Didn't know that. How can I do that? Also that means that instead of implementing a nested Ajax request, I can just have it in one and run the python script from that PHP script? I used the first Ajax to store data that is non-essential to the ML in the DB. @Chris G

Comment: You use [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for that.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how you can run that function in python with parameters using exec(). Kindly clarify. I've seen the PHP manual but there's no specification on that.

Comment: The first parameter you pass to `exec()` is just what you would type into a terminal window. Like `"python script.py param1 param2"`. (note that you have to @ me when you reply or I won't get notified)

Comment: I have created a dummy project that prints 'Hello world!' on python to test the exec() but unfortunately, my PHP doesn't display anything.  When I run `which python` on my terminal I get `/usr/bin/python` so I ran `exec('/usr/bin/python process.py')` and echoed it but I got not output. both files have read write access. Do you know what could be the problem? @ChrisG

Comment: When I use `exec('/usr/bin/python process.py 2>&1' ,$output,$status)` I get `sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found`. Terminal tells me that is the interpreter and when I execute the script directly on terminal with that path it works.

Comment: Here's one example of me using the command: `exec("sudo ./switch.py $pin $com", $output, $return);` the python script's first line is `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Thank you. @ChrisG. Ive fixed it and it works great. I noticed it was because I am using XAMPP-VM so my apache server could not access the system ENV variable `/usr/bin/python`